# Proxy ip's type checking

Tags: php, proxy

I have got 8000 proxies. And I wanna check their types. For example: I don't wanna use transparent ones.

Is it possible?

Comment: Need a website to check the X-FORWARDED-FOR header and curl (or facsimile) to make calls through the proxy to that page and verifying the outcome. Though I'd advise not going though 8k of them, unless you enjoy phone calls/emails from your host/isp.

Comment: im good at php curl. im gonna check out x-forwarded header. thanks for idea. i liked it. finally, i dont care what my isp thinks, they can not do anything. i can send 8 billion request, isp is no problem. i dont care

Comment: those 8000 proxies might care about the 1 million requests you'll be sending through each of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try to send requests via the proxies to your own site. Send requests with an unique parameter in the URL like http://www.myownsite.com/request.php?uid=some_unique_value .

Then you can use the request.php script to check what is coming, if it comes at all.